# In a VSTS build, where does the package version come from when setting "Automatic package versioning" to off?

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package

We're using VSTS to host our project. We've created a build that has Nuget Pack task.
This task should produce a nuget package, which it does. Where we're struggling is the versioning.

What version is used for the Nuget Package when you set "Automatic package versioning" to Off?

The "Include referenced projects" seems to be used even when you select one of the automaitc package versioning strategies. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package version default (when turn off Automatic package versioning) use the `AssemblyVersion` (or `AssemblyInformationalVersion` if has) from the **AssemblyInfo.cs** (for the project you pack) file:

- If `AssemblyInformationalVersion` exist in `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, the package version will use the version as `AssemblyInformationalVersion` by default.
- If `AssemblyInformationalVersion` does not exist in `AssemblyInfo.cs` file, the package version will use the version as `AssemblyVersion` by default.

Comment: Thanks! And if you have AssemblyInformationalVersion set in the AssemblyInfo.cs? Does it then use that instead? I did some testing and that is what seems to happen.
I find the phrase "Automatic Package versioining" a bit confusing. The option where the version is taking from AssenblyInfo.cs seems just as automatic (if not more so) than the one where you have to type in the semver and a date is added.

Comment: Yes, the AssemblyInformationalVersion will be usef if it exist in AssemblyInfo.cs file.

Comment: And if still you have any confusion about Automatic Package versioining, can you show the detail settings for this option?